# Why am I not able to install a lot of programs from the software center?

Tags: installation, software-center

For a lot of programs, I get this error to check my internet connection:

[image]

Comment: Scroll over to the right, so we can see what the full error messages say, there's likely important information right at the end of each line we can't see in your screenie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching the server you are downloading from Edit>"Software Sources."

For some reason I cannot connect property with the server in Canada so I have to switch to the main server and then everything works ok for me. That may or may not solve your problem but it is worth a try.